# Elegant way to merge 2 text files alphabetically line by line in Ruby

Tags: ruby, file-io

I have 2 log files that both contain lines of text starting with date stamps in chronological order. I want to merge both files into a single file that contains all lines from both files merged in chronological order. Due to the layout of the date stamps chronological in this case is the same as alphabetical.

I wrote a Ruby script that does this and it works fine, but I'm a Ruby novice just learning the language and one thing I really like about Ruby is all the syntactic sugar and the readability of the code. And I can't help but feel that my solution is quite clunky and there is surely a much nicer more elegant way to solve the same problem. I'm not necessarilly looking for algorithmically better, but syntactically. Ruby seems to have a one-liner solution for almost everything, so maybe for a problem like this too.

```
if ARGV.length != 2
    puts "Wrong number of arguments. Expected 2 arguments (path to 2 log files to be merged)"
end

merged_file = File.open("merge_out.txt", "w")
file1 = File.open(ARGV[0], "r")
file2 = File.open(ARGV[1], "r")

line1 = file1.gets
line2 = file2.gets

while (line1 != nil or line2 !=nil)
    if line1 == nil
        # no more line1 so write line2 and proceed file2
        merged_file.puts line2
        line2 = file2.gets        
    elsif line2 == nil
        # no more line2 so write line1 and proceed file1
        merged_file.puts line1
       line1 = file1.gets          
    else 
        comp = line1<=>line2
        #both lines present, write and proceed the (alphabetically) smaller one 
        #as this is the one with the earlier time stamp
        if comp == -1
            merged_file.puts line1
            line1 = file1.gets              
        else
            merged_file.puts line2
            line2 = file2.gets           
         end    
    end       
end
```

So, how can this be done more elegantly?

Comment: Your current solution has the benefit of low memory overhead. A lot of the nice Ruby syntax for `Array` is out of reach if we make the assumption that because these are log files then it is not safe to read the whole file. Which makes it an interesting question . . .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes adding a dimension makes a solution prettier. Essentially, turn your file1, file2 variables into an array `[ file1, file2 ]`, and this opens up a lot of Ruby `Array` syntax that performs the tests you have coded into your initial solution.

```
if ARGV.length < 2
    puts "Wrong number of arguments. Expected 2 or more files to merge."
end

merged_file = File.open("merge_out.txt", "w")

files = ARGV.map { |filename| File.open( filename, "r") }

lines = files.map { |file| file.gets }

while lines.any?
    next_line = lines.compact.min
    file_id = lines.index( next_line )
    merged_file.print next_line
    lines[ file_id ] = files[ file_id ].gets
end
```

So not only is this shorter, but as a side effect can handle more input files at once. Although if you don't need that, simply change back first check.

Comment: The winner!   Personally, I wouldn't have chosen this one, because as a non-native ruby person, I can't understand it.   Part of elegance for me is "self-explanatory", which the three liners both are.   But this just might be ignorance of the language - I'd be curious to see how quickly a native ruby programmer could answer "what does this do?"....

Comment: ... but on consideration part of the OP's goal was to learn interesting ruby idioms, so I guess this has that in spades :)

Comment: @GreenAsJade: This is basic Ruby using built-ins from `Array`. Probably the least intuitive part is finding out which file gave you the minimum line - `file_id = lines.index( next_line )` - if I could get rid of that I would. Otherwise it is "repeat: pick the best next line and output it" as per the OP, but without referencing "file A" vs "file B".

Answer (score 3):

I know it's not ruby, but for this kind of problem a simple bash command can do the work :

```
cat file1.dat file2.dat | sort > out.dat
```

If you really want ruby to do the work with a small piece of code :

```
File.open('out.dat','w') do |f|
 f.puts (File.read('file1.dat') << File.read('file2.dat') ).split("\n").sort
end
```

Please note that this doesn't take into account the fact that your data is already partially sorted. It's concise, but not necessarily the most efficient way to do it.

Comment: Nice, but is subject to the same slurping limitations as the first solution posted by @GreenAsJade, right?

Comment: The bash approach is not. I did the exact same thing to deal with data whose size were much larger than my ram, and you'd be amazed to see how fast it worked. Furthermore, this is actually a (very simple) example of a map/reduce approach. If needed, each step can easily be distributed among multiple nodes, which makes this approach much more scalable, if you're planning to deal with big data :)

Comment: The unix sort utility slurps it's whole input.  It has to, right?   It can't start outputing strings till it's read the last one in.  AFAIK the only way to avoid a slurp is to take advantage of the pre-sorted nature of the problem (or some highly complex thing involving intermediate sorted fragments in files).

Comment: I discovered I was wrong about this.   Interesting stuff:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20984382/why-doesnt-the-unix-sort-process-grow-as-it-consumes-its-input   ... sort does the whole temporary file fragments thing!

Answer (score 2):

You could merge your 4 cases into two cases: Simply ask yourself if line1 is the line to put first:

```
if line1 && line1 < line2 
    …
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't ruby syntax, but algorithmically, you can read each file into an array or list, then sort the array/list, then print it.   It looks nicer using a built-in to do the sort.  Depending on the implementation of the built-in, it may be faster than anything you can code, as well.   I guess you would only worry about performance if it becomes an issue :)

In python:

```
# create a list with all the first file in it as elements
with open(file1) as f:
    content = f.readlines()   

# add the second file contents to the list    
with open(file1) as f
    content = content + f.readlines()    # list catenation

content.sort()    # sort the list

# join all the lines in the list together into a string an print them
outfile.write(''.join(content))
```

Since you're a ruby novice, it will be a good learning exercise to find the equivalent ruby builtins :)

Note that this is not a good idea if the files are huge, though, because it is sucking the whole file into memory.   Once again - the price of simple code.   If you have humungous files, you need some clunkier code to process them :)

Edit:

I googled some ruby.  It *appears* that

```
# google "read file into array ruby"
array = IO.readlines file1_pathname + IO.readlines file2_pathname

# google "sort array ruby
array.sort

# google "print array ruby"
puts array.inspect
```

Is the kind of thing.

HTH

Comment: These are log files, so solutions should not assume that they can slurp whole file

Comment: @NeilSlater I noted the risk - but provided as close to a oneliners, without getting cryptic, as I could.  The OP specifically said "not improving the algorithm, just syntactically nicer".   I feel that I did the diligence in tackling the spirit of the question, without leading the OP wildly astray - indeed I introduced the kind of things you need to think about when you are trying to get "nice" with your oneliners.

Comment: This is exatly the kind of nice readable solution I was after, thanks. I understand the downside to it, but on the upside if available RAM allows slurping, this should not only be more concise code but also perform faster, right? I'm thinking because of more structured file-io in single batches or am I wrong?

Comment: @themik81: Even with small files, slurping a whole file is not guaranteed faster than line-by-line (one reason is OS caching of file reads into memory in blocks). It might be in this case, but you'd have to measure it.

Comment: One lesson about performance is that if it is a factor for you, then you need to measure it.   It is extremely hard for even experts to predict all the factors - it certainly takes a lot of experience.   My hope that the slurp solution would perform better is purely that sort() (in python) is likely to have an optimal internal implementation.   I grimaced at write(''.join(array)), which could be a _very_ long string.   I probably would not have written that in real code, but rather for line in array: write(line) - but that was two lines :)   The same might be true for array.inspect in ruby...

Comment: Neil gave one example of how performance can be tricky.  Here is another: in the line-by-line scenario, you are merging two previously sorted lists.   This (I think?) is O(n).   However, by doing slurp plus sort you are throwing away the advantage that they were previously sorted, and calling an unknown sort algorithm - which might have as it's worst case performance the type of list you are feeding it.  At best, you're looking at O(nlogn), which is definitely worse then your merge...  so you just never know, you have to measure...

Answer (score 1):

NeilSlater's comment on my other answer got my mind going on "so, if you can't slurp, then what?"

How about this:

```
line1 = file1.gets
line2 = file2.gets

while (line1 && line2)
    while(line1.to_s >= line2.to_s)  # to_s to protect against nil
        merged_file.puts line2
        line2 = file2.gets
    end        
    while(line2.to_s > line1.to_s)
        merged_file.puts line1
        line1 = file1.gets          
   end
end
while(line1)
   merged_file.puts line1
   line1 = file1.gets          
end
while(line2)
   merged_file.puts line2
   line2 = file2.gets      
end
```

It's not a lot shorter, and doesn't use any syntactic magic or handy builtins, but at least it is more regular...

Comment: Actually some of the logic here isn't quite right, and improvements to it should make the code cleaner. The first outer loop condition could simply be `while (line1 && line2)`, then you don't need to repeat that test inside the loop (also the inner conditions should be `if` and not `while` otherwise you *do* need to test for nils and bail out of outer loop early if you see any)

Comment: You do need to keep testing inside the loop, because you keep reading inside the inner loops.  While line1 is greater than line2, you keep reading file2 ... until line1 is no longer greater than line2, at which point line2 is greater than line1 and so you do the same for file1.   I tidied up the outer loop condition, thanks.